# List key-value pairs in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a Windows batch script to deal with a user input. The input string looks like the following:

```
key1=value1 key2=value2 key3="value 3"
```

i.e. a sequence of pairs separated with a whitespace, with each pair having a format of *key=value*, where *value* may be quoted. A quoted value may contain spaces. Amount of such pairs is not fixed - from 1 to any reasonable number, depending on the user.

For every pair I will need to create an environment variable named *key* and assign *value* to it.

Initially I tried to iterate over that string with the code below (for demo I have the INPUT string hardcoded but normally it would be passed as a parameter to the script):

```
@ECHO OFF
set INPUT=key1=value1 key2=value2 key3="value 3"
for %%i in (%INPUT%) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

This didn't work since it split not only by whitespaces but also by = giving just the output sequence of single tokens rather than key=value pairs:

```
d:\home\work>testParameters.bat
key1
value1
key2
value2
key3
"value 3"
```

I see that `for /f %%i in ("%INPUT%")` might do the trick but it brings a different problem: as I've said earlier the number of pairs can vary and I am not clear how would I then iterate over all of them.

Any suggestions here, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set INPUT=key1=value1 key2=value2 key3="value 3"
for %%a in (%input%) do (
   if not defined varname (
      set varname=%%a
   ) else (
      set !varname!=%%a
      set "varname="
   )
)
```

Previous method works as long as the values have not comma, semicolon, space or equal-sign, unless they are enclosed in quotes.

Comment: +1 And wildcards are not allowed, not even in quotes

Comment: Perfect, thanks, it does what it has to!
Isn't there a way to tell the "for"-command not to split %input% by "=" in addition to spaces?